# Loop i and j, where i != j

Tags: java, math, combinations, combinatorics

For example I need to get all combinations of 2-values array with numbers {0, 1, 2} where this two numbers are not the same.
 I get

```
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 2
2 0 
2 1
```

and I ignore

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

Now I use

```
  for (int i= 0; i < L ; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < L; j++) {
                    if (i!= j) {
```

but it is very slow?
Any solution for this? L will be > 4000.

What am I doing is finding every combinations of splitting matrix to 4 sub-matrices

*example:*

```
 3 | 0   2  -8  -8
 5 | 3   2   2   3
 2 | 5   2   1   4
 -------------------
 3   4  -1 |  4  2
-3   6   2 |  4  3
```

and computing their sum using sum-table.

Related question: [Split matrix into 4 sub-matrices with lowest difference between their sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955158/split-matrix-into-4-sub-matrices-with-lowest-difference-between-their-sum)

So for matix I have one horizontal line and two vertical and I am computing sum of 4 matrices, but two vertical lines should not crate one big vertical line, so i != j.

**UPDATE 1** order of the pairs is relevant

Comment: You're talking about at least 15,996,000 combinations.  Yes, it'll be slow.

Comment: Actually it is loop inside another for loop, so I really need a hand on this one

Comment: @JohnDow: Do you need to check all 16 million combinations? Because there isn't a significantly faster way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: @JohnDow You can't get around the fact that there are 16 million combinations. That's just math. What you really want is to only generate what you actually *need*- and without more information about what you are using these numbers for, we can't help you with that.

Comment: Maybe you have 3D accelerated graphics and you're interested to learn [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)?

Comment: Just being nit-picky here, but since the order of the numbers in each 2-valued array is relevant, the word you're looking for is *permutations*, not *combinations*.

Answer (score 7):

you could improve the perfomance by:

```
for (int i= 0; i < L ; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1 ; j < L; j++) {
System.out.println.(i + " " + j + "\n" + j + " " + i);
}}
```

Comment: @SSpoke why? The complexity might be the same, but it will run faster (~half the time)

Comment: This is only a correct answer if the order of the `{i, j}` pairs are irrelevant.  Even then, it is only a factor of ~2 improvement.

Comment: @goten - Incorrect.  It is still O(N^2).  In fact, the loops will execute the inner loop body `L*(L-1)/2` times.

Comment: Complexity is O(N²) for both cases. In the opzimized version from goten he will run N times through the outer loop, and in average (N/2) times through the inner one.

Comment: Just ran this on and Intel Pentium and it took `100591 milliseconds`

Comment: my mistake. it will be faster, but the order is unchanged

Comment: @MirroredFate - A single datapoint is not meaningful.  Besides, I bet you forgot to account for JVM warmup in your benchmarking :-)

Comment: @StephenC I disagree. With the correct context, a single data point can be very useful.

In other news, without the expensive print statements, it took `15 milliseconds`.

Comment: @MirroredFate So that means that, since the number of print statements is the same, the answer is really less than an 0.02% improvement?

Comment: changed answer to use only one print statement

Comment: Using JohnDow's original method, with the `if` block and two print statements inside it, it took me `210962 milliseconds` to run when `L=4000`. Using goten's method, it took me `100591 milliseconds`.

Comment: @goten - The OP has pointed out that the order of the pairs IS relevant, so your optimization is not actually a valid one ... for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to get some benefit from

```
for (int i= 0; i < L ; ++i) {
  int j=0;
  for (; j < i; ++j) {
  }
  for (++j; j < L; ++j) {
  }
}
```

which avoids testing `L` while you're still testing `i`. I've also switched to pre-increment -- since you aren't using the result it *probably* doesn't make any difference after the optimizer is done with it, but postincrement is, conceptually, a more complicated operation unless there happens to be instruction-set support for it.

If you can change the order in which results are reported, this would be faster:

```
int L1=L-1;
for (int i=L1; i >=0 ; --i) {
  int j=L1;
  for (; j > i; --j) {
  }
  for (--j; j >=0; --j) {
  }
}
```

Testing against most values requires a subtraction. Testing against zero doesn't; it occurs "for free" when the value is loaded. In fact, you could improve it further:

```
int L1=L-1, i=L1;
do {
  int j=L1;
  do {
  } while(--j>i);
  while(--j>=0)
  {
  }
} while(--i >= 0);
```

That avoids the redundant initial test. (Note that you still need to test at the top of the second loop, in case i was 0.)

However, in fact the loop overhead is the least of your problems here; the System.out.println() calls are going to consume far more cycles than the loop control will.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the pairs is relevant (e.g. you want to consider both `{1, 2}` and `{2, 1}` as different), there is way to get a significant speedup at this level.

If the order of the pairs is irrelevant (e.g. you have considered `{1, 2}` you can skip `{2, 1}`), then @goten's Answer gives you a factor of 2 speedup. **UPDATE** the Question has been updated to confirm that the order is relevant ... so @goten's solution is not applicable.

You are unlikely to get a significant speedup by micro-optimizing it; e.g. turning it into a while loop, etc.  The JIT compiler is most likely doing the equivalent optimizations behind the scenes anyway.

If you want better speedup, you will need to change your overall algorithm so that you *don't need to* consider so many combinations.  Whether that is feasible will depend on your problem.

The other alternative to consider is processing the combinations in parallel.  However, that only helps if you have multiple cores ... and your problem / algorithm are suitable for parallelization.

**UPDATE** - Your problem (per the updated question), looks like it *should* be suitable for parallelization, though you may need to do some careful tuning to minimize the effects of memory contention in accessing the large shared input array.

Answer (score 1):

for given pole and c is size of pole

```
 long[] radky = new long[x];
        long cisloRadku = 0;


    long min = 0;
    int q;
    int radek = 0;

    for (q = 0; q < (x); q++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            radky[q] += pole[q][j];

        }

        cisloRadku += radky[q];
    }


    long hodnota1 = 0;
    long hodnota2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (x - 1); i++) {
        hodnota1 += radky[i];
        hodnota2 = cisloRadku - hodnota1;


        long druheMin = hodnota1 - hodnota2;

        if (druheMin < 0) {
            druheMin = druheMin * (-1);
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            min = druheMin;
        }
        if (min > druheMin) {
            min = druheMin;
            radek = i;
        }
    }

    long[][] poleHorni = new long[radek + 1][x];
    long[][] poleDolni = new long[x - (radek + 1)][x];


    for (int i = 0; i < (radek + 1); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            poleHorni[i][j] = pole[i][j];

        }

    }


    long[] soucetHornich = new long[x];
    long soucetSlopucuUp = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < radek + 1; j++) {
            soucetHornich[k] += poleHorni[j][k];
        }

        soucetSlopucuUp += soucetHornich[k];
    }


    long cislo1 = 0;
    long cislo2;
    int sloupec = 0;
    long min2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (x - 1); i++) {
        cislo1 += soucetHornich[i];
        cislo2 = soucetSlopucuUp - cislo1;

        long druheMin2 = cislo1 - cislo2;


        if (druheMin2 < 0) {
            druheMin2 = druheMin2 * (-1);
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            min2 = druheMin2;
            vysledky[0] = cislo1;
            vysledky[1] = cislo2;
        }
        if (min2 > druheMin2) {
            min2 = druheMin2;
            sloupec = i;
            vysledky[0] = cislo1;
            vysledky[1] = cislo2;
        }
    }


    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (int i = (radek + 1); i < (x); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            poleDolni[a][b] = pole[i][j];

            b++;
        }
        b = 0;
        a++;

    }


    long[] soucetDolnich = new long[x];
    long soucetSlopucuDown = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (x - (radek + 1)); j++) {
            soucetDolnich[k] += poleDolni[j][k];
        }

        soucetSlopucuDown += soucetDolnich[k];
    }

    long cislo1A = 0;
    long cislo2A;
    long min2A = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (x - 1); i++) {
        cislo1A += soucetDolnich[i];
        cislo2A = soucetSlopucuDown - cislo1A;

        long druheMin2A = cislo1A - cislo2A;


        if (druheMin2A < 0) {
            druheMin2A = druheMin2A * (-1);
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            min2A = druheMin2A;
            vysledky[2] = cislo1A;
            vysledky[3] = cislo2A;
        }
        if (min2A > druheMin2A) {
            min2A = druheMin2A;

            vysledky[2] = cislo1A;
            vysledky[3] = cislo2A;
        }



    long[] vyslRozdil = new long[6];
    vyslRozdil[0] = vysledky[0] - vysledky[1];
    vyslRozdil[1] = vysledky[0] - vysledky[2];
    vyslRozdil[2] = vysledky[0] - vysledky[3];
    vyslRozdil[3] = vysledky[1] - vysledky[2];
    vyslRozdil[4] = vysledky[1] - vysledky[3];
    vyslRozdil[5] = vysledky[2] - vysledky[3];
    long max = 0;
    long max2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (vyslRozdil[i] < 0) {
            vyslRozdil[i] *= -1;
        }
        max2 = vyslRozdil[i];
        if (i == 0) {
            max = max2;
        }
        if (max < max2) {
            max = max2;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max);
```